# ios not getting friend list of facebook using graph api

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios7, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to fetch friend list of login user without using "FBFriendPickerViewController". So I used Graph API to do so but its not giving me the list of friends. I can login successfully and can able to fetch login user's information as well. I have followed this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friendlists.

I have tried this code of snippet till now

```
-(IBAction)loginWithFacebook:(id)sender {

    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen || FBSession.activeSession.state ==FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {
        // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
        // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    } 
    else {
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions",@"manage_friendlists",@"public_profile",@"user_friends"]
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
                                     }];
    }
}


-(void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
    // If the session was opened successfully
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
        NSLog(@"Session opened");
        // Show the user the logged-in UI
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"%@",user);
            NSLog(@"email::: %@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
        }];
        return;
    }
    if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
        // If the session is closed
        NSLog(@"Session closed");
    }

    // Handle errors
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Error");
        NSString *alertText;
        NSString *alertTitle;
        // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
        if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
            alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
            alertText = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
            [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
        } else {

            // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
            if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"User cancelled login");

                // Handle session closures that happen outside of the app
            } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession){
                alertTitle = @"Session Error";
                alertText = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
                [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];

            } else {
                //Get more error information from the error
                NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];

                // Show the user an error message
                alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
                alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
                [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
            }
        }
        // Clear this token
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    }
}
```

Now after login I tried to fetch friend list for that I have written

```
- (IBAction)fetchFrinds:(id)sender {

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friendlists"
                                 parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,name"}
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {

                              NSLog(@"%@",result);
                          }];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Facebook Graph API 2.0 docs on Friendlists](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friendlists):

> ### /{user-id}/friendlists
>
> A person's ['friend lists'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friendlist/) - these are groupings of friends such as "*Acquaintances*" or "*Close Friends*", or any others that may have been created. They do not refer to the list of friends that a person has, which is accessed instead through the [/{user-id}/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends/) edge.

So, with your current request, you're getting the friend-lists rather than the list of friends.

---

For getting a list of friends, you need to refer to:

- [Facebook Graph API 2.0 docs on List of Friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends/)

---

**NOTE:**
Facebook seems to have changed it's implementation.
You can no longer get the entire list of friends.
Now... the list will be limited to only those friends who also happen to use your app.

To quote Facebook Graph API 2.0 doc:

> **Permissions**
>
> - A user access token with **user_friends** permission is required to view the current person's friends.
> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.

Comment: I want to fetch the list of all friends of user's profile "/me/friends" just give me the list of friends using same app.

Comment: @rohan : I think Facebook has changed itself and become more closed (which is ironical but anyways)... the doc says `This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request`. It's been awhile since I've used Facebook's graph api so can't say for sure but it seems you can't get a list of all the friends any more. You can only get a list of friends who have also used your app. Kinda like mutual friends. _Anyways... I'll update my answer_.

Comment: I've already looked at this, and only friends who use the app can be seen. In the end, I now have to put that embarrassing screen in my app that says "none of your friends use this app, thank you come again". Ugh.

Answer (score 2):

If by friendslist you mean a list of friends for the logged in user then the graph path is `me/friends`. Something like this works for me after you have opened an active `FBSession` with read permissions.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"id,name,picture",@"fields",nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if(error == nil) {
                              FBGraphObject *response = (FBGraphObject*)result;
                              NSLog(@"Friends: %@",[response objectForKey:@"data"]);
                          }
                      }];
```

Note that the result of the `FBRequestConnection` request on success is an `FBGraphObject` with the required information returned for key `'data'`.
You can open an active `FBSession` with read permission of just `basic_info` before making an `FBRequestConnection` for the list of friends.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanx for reply but I want to fetch list of all friends of login usre's profile.

Comment: FB does not accept 'basic_info' anymore. Information looks outdated.